# Count Words Using indexOf

Tags: java, count, indexof

I can't use arrays, only simple Java (`if`, `for`, `while`, `substring`, `length`, `indexOf`)

```
public int howManyWords(String s){
        
    myString = "I have a dream";
    int count = 1;
    int length = 0;
    while(count>=0){
        
        count = myString.substring(String.valueOf(length),myString.indexOf(" "));
        count++;
        length = myString.indexOf(" ");
    
    }
    
     return count;
}
```

Should return 4

Comment: _javadoc_ is your friend. Have a look at method [indexOf(String, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: How is a word defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the string you are testing does **not** contain leading or trailing spaces, because that affects the solution. The example string in your question does not contain leading or trailing spaces.

Simply call method `indexOf(String, int)` in a loop and in each iteration you set the `int` parameter to one more than what you got in the previous iteration. Once the value returned by method `indexOf()` is -1 (minus one), you are done. But don't forget to add the last word after you exit the loop.

```java
String myString = "I have a dream";
int count = 0;
int index = 0;
while (index >= 0  &&  index < myString.length()) {
    index = myString.indexOf(" ", index);
    System.out.println("index = " + index);
    if (index >= 0) {
        index++;
        count++;
    }
}
if (index < 0) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

Comment: Fails for `String s = "";`

Comment: @Abra needs to change "s" to "myString"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you made infinite loop, because `count` is `1`, and you just increase it.

Second, you haven't even try to write this code in some IDE, because it would throw you a syntax error, because you are assigning `string` to `int`, when you do `count = myString.substring()`

So, instead of using `count` in loop, you can use `myString.indexOf`

something like this could work if you don't care what is going to happen with `myString`

```java
int count = 0;

while(myString.indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
  count++;
  myString = myString.substring(myString.indexOf(" ") + 1)
}

return count;
```

Comment: it never ends. The compiler I'm using just keeps running

Comment: _First of all,_ the code in the question does not compile, so I don't know how you determined that it is an infinite loop. Does it compile for you?

Comment: in the question, it doesn't. I added this code so that people know what kind of code I'm looking for.

Comment: `myString.substring(myString.indexOf(" "))` should be: `myString.substring(myString.indexOf(" ")+1)`

Comment: yup, my mistake, it should be with +1 when doing substring
then, it will work. Didn't test it out, just wrote it theoretically. Thanks @OlivierGrégoire

Answer (score 0):

Edited : Added missing else case.

Try the following code :

Remove the counted words from your string using the substring and indexOf, and increment the count in each iteration.

```
public int countWords(String s){
        
    String myString = "I have a dream";
    int count = 0;
    int length = myString.length();
    while(length>0){
        if((myString.indexOf(" ")!=-1) && (myString.indexOf(" ")+1)<length){
            myString = myString.subString(myString.indexOf(" ")+1);
            count++;
            length = myString.length();
        }
        else {
            length = 0;
            break;
        }
    
    }
    
     return count;
}
```

PS: Conventionally, your method names should denote actions, hence I suggested it to be countWords instead of howManyWords.

Comment: it never ends. The compiler I'm using just keeps running @SwathiMudda

Comment: this part of code miss `else` block in while loop
in that `else` block, you should add `length = 0`, and it should break while loop